# Duende IdentityServer 6.1.6 - Not able to Single Signout between implicit vs authorization_code grant type

Tags: duende-identity-server, implicit-flow, single-sign-out

Please help us on below issues-

We are not able to perform Sigle Signout between our apps -

- Angular 13 application (implicit flow) [angular-oauth2-oidc package]
- Dot Net Framework Asp.Net MVC application (authorization_code) [Frontend Channel Logout package]

**Issue 1:**
When **sessionChecksEnabled set to true** facing continuous **session_changed** events even no session is changed.
[image]

**Issue 2**
After Logout from angular application, the MVC Frontend Channel Logout URI get Hit and but it is not logging out the application. The session remain valid

[image]

**Identity Server Startup.cs**
[image]
[image]